Weekly Workout plan
This is my weekly workout plan just wanted to get feedback and advice.

Monday: cycling in the morning and evening push-ups, abs, weights for
tone and HIIT sprints.

Tuesday: push-ups, abs, weights and rowing HIIT.

Wednesday: rest day.

Thursday: push-ups, abs, weights and HIIT sprints.

Friday: cycling in the morning, evening push-ups, abs, weights for
tone and HIIT sprints.


Weekend rest and stretching.
My goal is get fully toned in my arms and abs. I currently weigh 180 lbs and I am 6 feet tall. I don't eat junk food, I added more protein to my diet and have a daily smoothie along with supplements. Anything else that would help? Thank you everyone.

Welcome to the stack, take the [tour] when you have a moment. You haven’t given us much to go on here, this is just a list of activities. To be able to give an answer, we need to know about your goals as well as a lot more detail about what you’re actually doing.

Definitely, more details are needed.  Especially as regards rowing.
